# Vuex - Adding array of object to the store takes a long time

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuex

I am doing this in a mutation in Vuex:

```
console.time('ADD products')
state.products = products
console.timeEnd('ADD products')
```

The 'products' is an array of 350 objects. The state.product is declared in the store like:

```
const state = {
  products: [],
...
}
```

The console.time/timeEnd is telling me this takes around 70ms to do. This cannot be as fast as it is supposed to be.

I have tried turning the strict mode on and off, as mentioned as a solution in similar posts, but with no effect at all.

Info:
Vue: 2.5.13
Vuex: 3.0.1
Debugging on latest version of Chrome on MacBook Pro

A product in the array looks like this:

```
{
  id: 9633,
  title: 'Dark Grey Canvas Satchel',
  brand: 'Delton Bags',
  price: '£49',
  beforePrice: false,
  isNew: false,
  discount: 0,
  link: 'http://localhost:3000/dark-grey-canvas-satchel-p.html',
  images: [
    'https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/f_auto,c_pad,q_80,w_X-WIDTH,h_X-HEIGHT/media/catalog/product/9/0/9027A-2.jpg',
    'https://res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/f_auto,c_pad,q_80,w_X-WIDTH,h_X-HEIGHT/media/catalog/product/h/d/hd-trendhim-12-2016-12.jpg',
  ],
  basePrice: 449,
  localPrice: 49,
  filters: {
    th_filter_farve: ['228'],
    th_filter_materiale: ['351'],
    th_filter_computersize: ['573'],
    th_brand: ['277'],
    th_price: 49,
  },
  filterAttributes: { canBeShortened: 0 },
  sorting: {
    qty_ordered: 47,
    qty_ordered_store: 0,
    newest: '9633',
    defaultSorting: 0,
  },
}
```

What I am asking:

1. What can I expect the speed to be
2. Would any computed properties relying on this state.products be slowing this performance down?
3. What is the fastest way to add an array like this to the store?

Regards
Kasper

Comment: Make sure your templates are not rerendering everytime you add an object

Comment: @Sirence Thanks, but I can strip all templates so the APP does nothing but creating the products. It still gives the same result.

Comment: Turning the strict mode off did help after all. It changed the speed from 70ms to 20ms.

But still it seems like a lot as looping though the array and adding extra properties to each object only takes around 1ms.

Comment: are you syncing the state to localstorage/sessionstorage? that could  slow things down as all localstorage/sessionstorage operation is synchronous and it's writing to disk, not memory